# Is there a DOS prompt (cmd.exe from Win7) command to eject a thumb drive?

Tags: command-line, usb-flash-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove USB device from command line](https://superuser.com/questions/443162/remove-usb-device-from-command-line)

Win7 laptop is in recovery mode where only DOS prompt is available for issuing commands. Is there a cmd.exe command that does the same as this to eject a thumb drive?     [image]

Comment: Nitpicking. Replace "DOS prompt" with "cmd.exe, or any other shell on a black background, but not DOS".

Comment: @zundarz: See latter half of my answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/486647/138343) and let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not from recovery mode, but as long as there are no active I/O processes, you should be fine to just pull it.

unless you're livebooting, then NEVER PULL IT unless told to by the live OS.

Comment: There should be a way to do this in the Recovery Console as well. @zundarz: See my answer [in the linked thread](http://superuser.com/a/486647/138343) (obviously couldn't post here due to the thread closure, which like Jared I tried asking about in chat but the mods were apparently too busy or asleep to reply).