# Is there a program to enable/disable a computer's DVD-ROM drive with a mouse click?

Tags: windows-7, optical-drive

Frequently I have a DVD-disk left in the DVD-ROM drive, which I am kind of reluctant to take out. I have Windows-7 OS which freezes constanly checking on that disk. I do not need that constant checking, because I know what disk I have in the drive.

Is there a way to turn off the DVD-drive when I do not need to use it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. See my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/486647/138343) for a link to **DevCon** for Win7.
2. Use `devcon find *CDROM*` or `devcon listclass CDROM` at an *elevated* command prompt to see a list of installed physical and virtual optical drives, for example:

   ```
   IDE\CDROMSAMSUNG_DVD-ROM_SD-608__________________2.2_____\4&13B4AFD&0&0.0.0: SAMSUNG DVD-ROM SD-608
   SCSI\CDROM&VEN_CONTOSO&PROD_VIRTUAL_DVD-ROM&REV_1.0A\1&2AFD7D61&0&0000: Contoso Virtual DVD-ROM0000
   2 matching device(s) found.
   ```
3. Use the complete device ID string returned or figure out which portion(s) of the string returns *only* the drive you want to enable/disable. For example, a sub-string such as ***CDROMSAMSUNG*** or ***CDROM*608*** is sufficient to uniquely identify the physical drive, such that
   `devcon find *CDROMSAMSUNG*` returns:

   ```
   IDE\CDROMSAMSUNG_DVD-ROM_SD-608__________________2.2_____\4&13B4AFD&0&0.0.0: SAMSUNG DVD-ROM SD-608
   1 matching device(s) found.
   ```
4. The rest is easy! Just use `devcon disable *CDROMSAMSUNG*` and
   `devcon enable *CDROMSAMSUNG*` to do what you want.

   Additionally, `devcon status *CDROMSAMSUNG*` will tell you whether "Driver is running" or "Device is disabled".

---

**Edit:** You can create **ToggleCD.bat** as follows:

```
devcon status *CDROMSAMSUNG* | find "Driver is running" && devcon disable *CDROMSAMSUNG* && goto :EOF
devcon status *CDROMSAMSUNG* | find "Device is disabled" && devcon enable *CDROMSAMSUNG* && goto :EOF
```

Ensure **devcon.exe** is in a directory that's in your PATH (for example, copy it to your Windows directory), and obviously replace ***CDROMSAMSUNG*** with the actual string that you identified using the instructions above.

To keep UAC on and yet bypass the prompt for the shortcut to the batch file, read the [Create Administrator Mode Shortcuts Without UAC Prompts in Windows 7 or Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-administrator-mode-shortcuts-without-uac-prompts-in-windows-vista) article.

Comment: Hi, Karan! Thank you for your answer. I did not have a chance to check it today, though I have downloaded devcon already through the link that you provided. I will test it tomorrow, hopefully.

Comment: @GreenBear: It should work just fine, I made sure to test it on my system before posting. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi, Karan! Devcon is working! But I have a few more questions. I am thinking of making a "bat" file "Toggle Drive Status" - user clicks a shortcut on a desktop an the drive is either disabled or enabled. First question: is it possible to read output from the "devcon status" command and depending on that output run either "devcon disable" or "devcon enable"? My "DOS language" is very very rusty. Second: is it possible to turn off UAC notifications for the "bat" file and for the devcon.exe? I do not want to turn UAC completely off for all other stuff.

Comment: Third question: is it possible to set so, that when a user clicks the shortcut, the "bat" file and devcon are run "as administrator"? I created the shortcut, but for some reason the "run as administrator" checkbox is greyed (disabled).
Thank you again. I would not bother you, but since you are an expert, maybe these are easy for you, or if you can just provide me a link, that will do as well.

Comment: @GreenBear: Check the edit above.

Comment: Karan, as soon as the snow melts I will build a monument in your honor :-). Thank you for the help. I will test it tomorrow, I am sure it will work.

Comment: "as soon as the snow melts" - Why wait? I've always had a hankering to be immortalised [thus](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ytMiv.jpg). :D

Comment: That way I would have to keep it in the freezer, and I dread to think what could happen should the power go down :-) You rock, man! It all works.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is, you can disable DVD-drive. Go to Control Panel -> Administrative tools -> Computer management -> click on Device manager, select DVD/CD-ROM drives, right click on your drive and click "Disable". Enable it again when you want to use it :)

Comment: Hi, Davidenko! Thanks for the help! This works, but what I would like more is a sort of shortcut on the desktop to save the time. So the best would be a programm, a bat file or a script, and would be great if it could also report a status. Any more ideas? Can this be done, say in a script?

Comment: I can help you when I get home, I'm currently at work, on XP :)

Comment: I just remembered, try http://freshtutorial.com/disable-autoplay-windows-7/ if it's constantly checking on that disk

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Sadly, "The Local Group Policy Editor feature is not included in the Windows 7 Starter, Home Basic, and Home Premium editions." I am a happy owner of the Home Basic :(

Comment: @GreenBear: "I am a happy owner of the Home Basic" - What Group Policy Editor does can also be directly done via registry edits if the appropriate keys/values are known. Uwe Sieber's [AutoRun Settings](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/drivetools_e.html) might also be of use to you, in addition to my answer above.

Comment: Thanks a LOT, Karan, for such a valuable link. In the past I had a lot of troubles with autorun on my old XP laptop, and since they do not make TweakUI for Win7, I was wondering if I had autorun "on" on my new laptop. It is good to know that now it is "off" for good. One thing still bothers me: the "HonorAutorunSetting" was off and was greyed (disabled). Do you know if I need to create such key manually, or if it matters at all?

Comment: @GreenBear: You can check if the value's missing in the registry and if so, create it. See [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967715 "How to disable the Autorun functionality in Windows") for instructions and better still, FixIt tools you can use to do the work automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Click Start and type (without quotes) "diskmgmt.msc". Right click the result and select Run as Administrater. Follow the UAC prompt and Disk Manager will open. Find your SATA CD/DVD Drive and right click it. There should be an option to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this a long time ago.  The cure was to load a program that recorded any mouse movement and any mouse clicking. It could record the actions for instance of selecting Device Manager, selecting DVD/CD ROM DRIVES, and then choosing "Disable device".

This was then accessible via a desktop shortcut.
The process of "Enable device" was also recorded and was also accessible via a desktop shortcut.