# How can I disable/enable multiple hardware components with a single command?

Tags: windows-8.1, script, powershell, shell-script

I am a web developer/designer during the day, but at night I play DJ gigs. For music, I need several hardware components disabled. Then, after the gig, I reenable all of the hardware. Each of these operations takes about 10-15 minutes.

I have read some documentation on using PowerShell to accomplish this, but I have never been able to produce a working script that will do the stuff I need all in one go. Shell scripting has never been a particular strong point of mine.

A batch file, or some other script would be preferable to a full-blown app. I realize that a few "game boosters" will disable services, but none (that I have found) offer one-click hardware enable/disable functionality. It seems like a no-brainer (to me, anyway), but to my knowledge no such code/app/script exists.

P.S.: Currently on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable/disable a hardware from Windows 7 command line](http://superuser.com/questions/564157/how-to-enable-disable-a-hardware-from-windows-7-command-line)

Comment: What are the hardware components that you want to stop?