# How to poweroff CD drive in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, power-management, thinkpad, compact-disc

I am running Windows 7 64 bit on Lenovo W510, I wish to poweroff the CD drive. The power manager sometimes switches off the power when I am running on batteries. Is there a way I can do that myself.

**EDIT:** The reason I wish to poweroff the CD drive as it is a faulty one and keeps on ejecting the bay every 5 - 10 mins, even when there is no CD inserted. This is distracting and I can't replace it as its an office laptop.

Comment: I don't believe you can selectively power down just the optical drive on your laptop. Follow my answer here: [Is there a program to enable/disable a computer's DVD-ROM drive with a mouse click?](http://superuser.com/questions/561072/is-there-a-program-to-enable-disable-a-computers-dvd-rom-drive-with-a-mouse-cli) and you can accomplish what you want by enabling/disabling the drive on demand.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no CD/DVD in the drive, there should be no power drawn by it. The drive uses the most power when its spinning the motor and reading/writing to the disk. If it is not doing this it should not be drawing any additional power.

Edit:
Have you checked that it is not a software issue causing the tray to be ejected? I've come across several pieces of software which cause the tray to be ejected randomly. Even some viruses cause this kind of behaviour. If its a work laptop, you can probably get them to replace it for you, they should be more than willing to do this if its affecting your productivity.

Comment: Agreed, but do you know how to poweroff the cd drive anyway.

Comment: The only thing to do that would actually stop all power being sent to it would be to unplug it. Modern drives can usually be removed fairly safely if they aren't in use. Even your hard drive which windows switches off for power saving isn't actually completely switched off