# HP EliteBook 8470p laptop's DVD drive spins up periodically when the DVD drive is empty

Tags: windows-7, dvd, hp-elitebook, spinup

I recently got an HP EliteBook 8470p with Windows 7, and the DVD drive (HP DVD A DS8A9SH) spins up briefly at some interval, maybe a minute, as if something is checking if a DVD is present or similar. The drive is empty.

This is extremely irritating. Of course, if I pop out the DVD tray it stops, but that should not be the solution. I assume it can be some bloatware or maybe the DVD model has a bad driver? Is there a setting somewhere that can turn this off?

I have tried to Google this, but the search terms become so general (spin DVD periodically, etc.) that I can't seem to find any information about this.

Comment: You can download Process Monitor and see which process is trying to access the DVD drive

Comment: I've seen this happen with drives that're going bad as well (meaning it might be a hardware problem). If that's the case and a replacement is not immediately possible, you might find my answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/561495/138343) to be of use.

Answer (score 0):

You can always disable the drive from "Device manager" if you didn't already.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, and have traced it to iTunes. If I close iTunes, the problem goes away. I am on the current version of iTunes which is 11.1.3.8.  Hopefully Apple will fix this issue in future versions. I don't recall it ever being an issue in previous versions. For now when I have iTunes open, I just leave the drive door open.