# Scan for hardware changes

Tags: windows-8, boot, lan, network-adapter

In windows 8 PCs, the network will not connect at startup. If we do the "scan for hardware changes" in Device manager, then only network will connect. But the same pc was connecting in windows XP. After installing windows 8 only we faced the problem. So what we have to do to load network at startup? Or any option to create& load a bat file or reg file to scan hardware changes at startup?
Got some answer to use like DevCon.exe and create script. But DevCon.exe is not installing in our windows 8 64 bit OS.
What we can do?

Comment: You should add some more information about your PC. Network card? Motherboard?

Comment: See my answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/486647/138343) for link to 64-bit DevCon which I use with Win7 and should work on Win8 too. But that's a workaround, not an actual solution for your problem.