# Safely remove or ejecting USB

Tags: windows, windows-8, usb

This is my USB Flash in another PC. As you can see it shows the option to eject the Flash Drive

[image]

This is my USB in my PC. And it doesn't show the option to eject the 
Flash Drive

[image]

The only solution I've found until now is to eject the USB from the context menu on "my computer"

[image]

Why does this happens and how can I solve it?

Comment: You probably have the drive set to "Quick Removal" on your PC.  Check the drives properties while it's plugged in.

Comment: thanks for your answer but unfortunately that did not solve the problem

Comment: Does this happen on other computers?

Comment: Hi Gabriel 
No,It does not happen

Comment: Related: [Remove USB device from command line](http://superuser.com/questions/443162/remove-usb-device-from-command-line), for ways of safely removing the drive.

Answer (score 3):

It is currently not an issue if you just remove the drive without ejecting.  As long as the drive is not in use and you remove it, it will be fine.  However, if you are transferring files to or from the drive do not disconnect.  Promise if you follow those rules you will be golden.

However, if you are one of those people who is transferring really sensitive data that you cannot afford to lose you will want to make sure you are safely removing it.

I would recommend that you close out all explorer tasks and make sure that no app is running.  This is a sure way to know nothing is being transferred.

I also found this article on the web for you to read if you want more information.

[Article about USB safe removal](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2040932/how-to-safely-remove-a-usb-drive-even-when-windows-says-it-isnt-safe-to-do-so.html)

Comment: Yes,I know. I follow those rules,but the problem is that in the tray appears the icon but does not appear the option "Eject AnyDrive" on my laptop(like I explained before) ,nevertheless it appears on others and I need to solve this because others people use my laptop and they always try to eject the drive