# Can USB drives still be read or written to after hitting "Eject" in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, usb, security, windows-11, usb-flash-drive

After hitting "Eject" in Windows explorer, without removing the USB stick, can it still be read or written to by other software? If I leave it plugged in is there any risk of other software accessing my USB?

Comment: Could be possible to connect the device to a virtual machine without unplugging. Didn't try it.

Answer (score 0):

After being ejected, a USB disk can no longer be accessed.

However, it's very easy for a program to undo the Eject.

See for example the post
[How to access an ejected USB flash drive without removing and plugging it back in](https://superuser.com/questions/903651/how-to-access-an-ejected-usb-flash-drive-without-removing-and-plugging-it-back-i),
which contains links to several utilities that can do just that.

Comment: Also, a reboot would make it see as plugged in again.