# Is there a way to format and eject multiple external drives through command line ( windows)?

Tags: command-line, format, eject

I'm in the process of formatting hundreds of micro sd cards and I am looking for an easy way to format and eject them in bulk.  I have 9 sd card slots and can add more if needed.  Currently I am using SDFormatter but it only allows one at a time formatting and doesn't eject the disks.  Is there a script that will let me do this faster?

Comment: Does it work this this (http://superuser.com/questions/443162/remove-usb-device-from-command-line) or does that eject your whole USB device. (which would require un- and re-plugging that).

Comment: @Hennes That's half of it, thanks.  I guess I should have researched each step individually.  Must have been an off morning for me.